# Get free capacity of an ocfs2 volume

Tags: filesystems, mount, ocfs2

I want to get free capacity of an ocfs2 volume (ocfs2-tools version 1.6), which is not mounted any where. Is there way to do that. Thanks

Comment: Have you not found the info in the user guide? https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2-tools/dist/documentation/v1.4/ocfs2-1_4-usersguide.pdf . After you mount it, it should be visible to the OS.

Comment: I want to get this information without mounting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found o2info tools, which can provide free capacity of an ummounted ocfs2 volume